# Good ways to convert 2d array to object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

With <s>ES7</s> ES2017 (ES8) I can convert an object to an array of arrays like this:

```
let obj = { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
let arr = Object.entries(obj)
// [ [ 'a', '1' ], [ 'b', '2' ], [ 'c', '3' ] ]
```

But what if I want to go the other way around? I could use a for-loop, or the reduce-method of the Array like below, but is there a more direct approach?

```
let arr =[ [ 'a', '1' ], [ 'b', '2' ], [ 'c', '3' ] ]
let obj = arr.reduce((o, x)=>{o[x[0]]=x[1];return o}, {})
// { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
```

A use case: I wanted to convert a string like `"a=1;b=2;c=3"` to an object like `{ a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }` and ended up with something like

```
"a=1;b=2;c=3"
  .split(";")
  .reduce((o, x)=>{
    let parts=x.split("=")
    o[parts[0]]=parts[1]
    return o
  }, {});
```

***Edit:*** As pointed out in comments, the reduce syntax could be simplified (or shortened, at least) to:

```
arr.reduce((o, [k, v])=>(o[k]=v, o), {})
```

...or written with `Object.assign` like this:

```
arr.reduce((o, [k, v])=>Object.assign(o, {[k]: v}), {})
```

Either way, the answer to the question, according to the comments, is **no**. This is the best approach we've got.

Edit, Jan 2023: `.fromEntries()` [is in stage 4](https://tc39.es/proposal-object-from-entries/) since 2019, and now [supported in all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_fromentries).

Comment: You can shorten/simplify the callback to `(o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: v})`, but other than that no there's nothing better

Comment: It's ES2017, not ES7. It's either as Bergi explained or `.reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = v, o), {})` (faster but comma smells).

Comment: @estus Thanks, I'll update the question.

Comment: generally this is what utility libs are for (e.g. lodash's [_.fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#fromPairs))

Comment: I've updated the tags to be correct. Object.entries belongs to ES2017. ES7 and ES8 are deprecated colloquial terms, such specs don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want some *one-line* `unentries` function?

```js
const detries = entries => entries.reduce((result, [key, value]) => Object.assign(result, {[key]: value}), {});

const entries = Object.entries({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
const detried = detries(entries);

console.info("ENTRIES", entries);
console.info("DETRIED", detried);
```

---

## Edit: [`Object.fromEntries` proposal](https://github.com/bakkot/object-from-entries).

You will probably be able to use this one instead.

> `Object.fromEntries` is proposed to perform the reverse of `Object.entries`: it accepts an iterable of key-value pairs and returns a new object whose own keys and corresponding values are given by those pairs.

```
Object.fromEntries([["apple", 0], ["banana", 1]]) // {apple: 0, banana: 1}
```