# Javascript: quick object initialization by list

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have the object `a`

```
const a = {
  string1: 'prop1',
  val1: 'value1',
  string2: 'prop2',
  val2: 'value2'
}
```

then I can easily instantiate a new constant object `b`

```
const b = { [a['string1']]: a['val1'], [a['string2']]: a['val2'] };
```

which will result in

```
b = { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2' }
```

But what if I have instead a list `lst`

```
const lst = [['prop1','value1'], ['prop2','value2']]
```

and I want to instantiate `b` from `lst` in a neat way? The furthest I got was

```
const b = {};
for(const tpl of lst){
  b[tpl[0]] = tpl[1];
}
```

But me, being a big fan of oneliners, do not really like this code. So how can I quickly initialise `b` from a list of properties?

**EDIT**
It seems my question was not posed abstractly enoughed.
Let me reclarify it.
Suppose I have the list `l = ['prop1', 'prop2'];`

and the function `fx(str) { return str.substring(1); }`
How could I now quickly initialize the object `b` such that

```
b = {
  prop1: 'rop1',
  prop2: 'rop2'
}
```

I cannot do `b= {[l[0]]=fx(l[0]), [l[1]]=fx(l[1])}` since the list `l` is dynamicly generated and will contain an unknown amount of variables. So somehow it would be nice to loop
e.g. this non-existent syntax

```
b = { [[for str in l]] : fx(str) }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good ways to convert 2d array to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296668/good-ways-to-convert-2d-array-to-object)

Answer (score 3):

You have entries there, so you can just:

```
Object.fromEntries(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Uroš](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7097045/uro%C5%A1-an%C4%91eli%C4%87)  mentioned Object.fromEntries(lst) is the best method for this.
As an alternative you can use `reduce`.

```js
const lst = [['prop1','value1'], ['prop2','value2']]

const b =  lst.reduce(function(prev,curr){prev[curr[0]]=curr[1];return prev;},{})
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.values()` method

```js
const b = {};
const lst = [
  ['prop1', 'value1'],
  ['prop2', 'value2'],
];

for (const [key, value] of lst.values()) b[key] = value;

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Surely this code would work without `.values()` too?